# Cannot remove item from Shopping Cart android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, shopping-cart

I referred [this][1] and [this][2] site and tried to modify it according to my own needs. Problem is I can't remove an item from the cart. I have tried everything including searching for solutions in stackoverflow and google but no luck.

Here is my **CatalogActivity.java**

```
package com.comlu.sush.shoppingcart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import java.util.List;

public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Product> mProductList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        // Obtain a reference to the product catalog
        mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

        // Create the list
        ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
        listViewCatalog.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(mProductList, getLayoutInflater(), false,false));

        listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
                startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
            }
        });

        Button viewShoppingCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonViewCart);
        viewShoppingCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent viewShoppingCartIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShoppingCartActivity.class);
                startActivity(viewShoppingCartIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**ShoppingCartHelper.java**

```
package com.comlu.sush.shoppingcart;   
import android.content.res.Resources;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector; 

public class ShoppingCartHelper {
public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";
private static List<Product> catalog;
private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();

    public static List<Product> getCatalog(Resources res){
        if(catalog == null) {
            catalog = new Vector<Product>();
            catalog.add(new Product("Dead or Alive", res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.first),
                    "Dead or Alive by Tom Clancy with Grant Blackwood", 29.99));
            catalog.add(new Product("Switch", res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.second),
                    "Switch by Chip Heath and Dan Heath", 24.99));
            catalog.add(new Product("Watchmen", res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.third),
                    "Watchmen by Alan Moore and Dave Gibbons", 14.99));
        }

        return catalog;
    }

    public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
        if(quantity <= 0) {
            if(curEntry != null)
                removeProduct(product);
            return;
        }

        // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
        if(curEntry == null) {
            curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
            cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
            return;
        }

        // Update the quantity
        curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        if(curEntry != null)
            return curEntry.getQuantity();

        return 0;
    }

    public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
        cartMap.remove(product);
    }

    public static List<Product> getCartList() {
        List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
        for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.add(p);
        }

        return cartList;
    }
}
```

**ShoppingCartActiity.java**

```
package com.comlu.sush.shoppingcart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class ShoppingCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Product> mCartList;
    private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_cart);

        mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();

        // Make sure to clear the selections
        for(int i=0; i<mCartList.size(); i++) {
            mCartList.get(i).selected = false;
        }

        // Create the list
        final ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
        mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(), true,true);
        listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

        listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                mProductAdapter.toggleSelection(position);

            }
        });

        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mProductAdapter.removeSelected();
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Refresh the data
        if(mProductAdapter != null) {
            mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

**ProductDetailsActivity.java**

```
package com.comlu.sush.shoppingcart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

        final int result=0;

        List<Product> catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

        int productIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
                ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);
        final Product selectedProduct = catalog.get(productIndex);

        // Set the proper image and text
        ImageView productImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProduct);
        productImageView.setImageDrawable(selectedProduct.productImage);
        TextView productTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductTitle);
        productTitleTextView.setText(selectedProduct.title);
        TextView productDetailsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductDetails);
        productDetailsTextView.setText(selectedProduct.description);

        // Update the current quantity in the cart
        TextView textViewCurrentQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentlyInCart);
        textViewCurrentQuantity.setText("Currently in Cart: "
                + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(selectedProduct));


        // Save a reference to the quantity edit text
        final EditText editTextQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);

        Button addToCartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonAddToCart);
        addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Check to see that a valid quantity was entered
                int quantity = 0;
                try {
                    quantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextQuantity.getText()
                            .toString());

                    if (quantity < 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "Please enter a quantity of 0 or higher",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter a numeric quantity",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return;
                }

                // If we make it here, a valid quantity was entered
                ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(selectedProduct, quantity);

                // Close the activity
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
package com.comlu.sush.shoppingcart;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Product> mProductList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private boolean mShowQuantity;
    private boolean mShowCheckbox;

    public ProductAdapter(List<Product> list, LayoutInflater inflater, boolean showQuantity, boolean showCheckbox) {
        mProductList = list;
        mInflater = inflater;
        mShowQuantity = showQuantity;
        mShowCheckbox = showCheckbox;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewItem item;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            item = new ViewItem();

            item.productImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ImageViewItem);

            item.productTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextViewItem);

            item.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);

            item.productCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxSelected);

            convertView.setTag(item);
        } else {
            item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Product curProduct = mProductList.get(position);

        item.productImageView.setImageDrawable(curProduct.productImage);
        item.productTitle.setText(curProduct.title);

        if(!mShowCheckbox) {
            item.productCheckbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if(curProduct.selected == true)
                item.productCheckbox.setChecked(true);
            else
                item.productCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        }

        // Show the quantity in the cart or not
        if (mShowQuantity) {
            item.productQuantity.setText("Quantity: "
                    + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(curProduct));
        } else {
            // Hid the view
            item.productQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    Product selectedProduct = (Product) getItem(position);
    if(selectedProduct.selected) { // no need to check " == true"
        selectedProduct.selected = false;
    }
    else {
        selectedProduct.selected = true;
    }
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
public void removeSelected() {
        for(int i=mProductList.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(mProductList.get(i).selected) {
                mProductList.remove(i);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private class ViewItem {
        ImageView productImageView;
        TextView productTitle;
        TextView productQuantity;
        CheckBox productCheckbox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your Logcat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 - Array larger than Index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869810/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0-array-larger-than-index)

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan Thanks for taking the time to comment. What do you suggest I do to make this work? I am a beginner in this so I don't know what I should be doing.

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan your link did not met my requirements. The error that occured was only after I tried something new. My app was already working properly and that was not the error I had mentioned in my question. The item gets removed from my cart but it is there again when I view it the second time. That's my problem.

Comment: If it crashed, there must be LogCat for that. Apply packagename and log level (warn, error, etc) filters.

Comment: `I have included my logcat` where? I can't see it in the question. Please update your question with LogCat.

Comment: @Sufian The app crashed before I modified my code. The code is working fine now. It's isn't crashing. Working fine. The problem is the item isn't getting removed from my cart even after I click the remove button. That's why I removed the log as I solved the previous crashing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move data manipulation to the adapter, and design-wise it would make sense and might also fix the problem you're telling us.

Write this method in your `ProductAdapter`:

```
public void removeSelected() {
    for(int i = mProductList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(mProductList.get(i).selected) {
             mProductList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Update your `OnClickListener` (in your `ShoppingCartActiity` of course):

```
removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         mProductAdapter.removeSelected();
     }
});
```

### Edit

I noticed that you aren't applying OOP's concept of encapsulation here. That is, `ShoppingCartActiity` shouldn't be making changes to the data which belongs to your adapter.

So, just create `public` methods inside the `ProductAdapter` for item for selection, etc and call them from `ShoppingCartActiity` as needed.

1. Copy this method in your `ProductAdapter`:

   ```
   public void toggleSelection(int position) {
       Product selectedProduct = (Product) getItem(position);
       if(selectedProduct.selected) { // no need to check " == true"
           selectedProduct.selected = false;
       }
       else {
           selectedProduct.selected = true;
       }
       notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   }
   ```
2. `mProductAdapter.toggleSelection(position);` will replace following code `ShoppingCartActiity`:

   ```
   Product selectedProduct = mCartList.get(position);
   if(selectedProduct.selected == true)
       selectedProduct.selected = false;
   else
       selectedProduct.selected = true;

   mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
   ```

### Edit2

The problem is that the `ShoppingCartActiity` takes items from `ShoppingCartEntry` on starting up, but it never writes back the changes to it when you remove items.

1. update your `removeButton`'s `onClick()` to:

   ```
   mProductAdapter.removeSelected();
   if (product.selected) {
       // set products which are remaining in the adapter
       ShoppingCartHelper.setProducts(mProductAdapter.getProducts());
   }
   ```
2. `ShoppingCartHelper.setProducts()` would replace the old data with the passed one:

   ```
   public static void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
       catalog = new Vector<Product>();
       for (Product product : products) {
           catalog.add(product);
       }
   }
   ```
3. `mProductAdapter.getProducts()` will just return the list of `Product`s, like:

   ```
   public List<Product> getProducts() {
       return mProductList;
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot for posting this code. I tried this but it gives me a JavaNullPointerException. `Then call it on button click:`. You meant in the button of ShoppingCartActivity right? I have updated my code acoording to what you suggested. Please provide a solution.

Comment: @Sushant firstly you're doing it all wrong. You should replace all of your `onClickListener` of your `removeButton` as I said, no need to put any other code than what I've put. Secondly, you're using my previous code of mine (which had one error around `notifyDataSetChanged()`). Thirdly, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the above code. But it doesn't work. There are absolutely no errors but the item's still in the cart. When I click the remove button it gets removed but when I view the shopping cart again the item is still there. I have updated my code as per your suggested code. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: "I click the remove button it gets removed but when I view the shopping cart again the item is still there". You question wasn't clear. What you're experiencing is that the cart shows the old data. You need to send it an updated list of products. It depends upon your scenario. If you could tell which Activity shows the list and briefly explain the flow of your app, I could update my answer with a possible solution for this too.

Comment: I have updated my question and included the CatalogActivity which is the launcher activity. It shows all the items from which you can select any item you want which then gets added to the ShoppingCartActivity. Here you can select any item that you want to remove by selecting that item. It is here where I am facing the problem. Items from the ShoppingCartActivity do not get removed even though I select the items and click the remove button. This is where I need help.

Comment: @Sushant when you call `mProductAdapter.removeSelected()`, you need to call similar method on your `ShoppingCartHelper`. Because in your `ShoppingCartActivity`, you get the list of products from `ShoppingCartHelper`.

Comment: @Sushant although I'm not a big fan of singletons, but the problem you're facing here is that every time you open `ShoppingCartActivity`, you get the data from your singleton but you never write changes made to it. And this is your only problem.

Comment: `when you call mProductAdapter.removeSelected(), you need to call similar method on your ShoppingCartHelper`. Yes that idea came to me but I am not a professional programmer so which method should I write so that the changes I make once are saved permanently?

Comment: @Sushant you'd remove the products if they're selected (`if (product.selected)`). Nothing too difficult if the code you've posted is your own work. ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for the above comment `(if (product.selected))`. That solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove selected item from list, and after adapter.notifiyDataSetChanged() it will refresh the adapter.

```
removeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Loop through and remove all the products that are selected
                    // Loop backwards so that the remove works correctly
                    for(int i=mCartList.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {

                        if(mCartList.get(i).selected) {
                            mCartList.remove(i);
                            //mProductAdapter.removeSelected();
                        }
                    }
                  if(mProductAdapter!=null)
                    mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Hey @AbdulRizwan. Sorry but your code didn't work. The item's still there the second time I check even after removing it from the list. Please help.